# Android Phonegap - Passing JSONObject to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

I'm trying to pass some information from an Android native class to the javascript.
I'm taking a bundle, converts it to JSONObject and passing the string representation of it.
But when trying to parse it in the JS, it fails.

This is what I do:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
        Object value = bundle.get(key);
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, value.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }

    final String jsStatement = String.format(
            "window.doSomething('%s');", jsonObject.toString());

    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + jsStatement);
        }
    });
```

Can you tell me why it's not being parsed in the JS and how can I solve it?

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Anything in logcat?

Comment: Yes, it gets to the JS method and when I'm trying to do JSON.parse(...) with the received string it says "Unexpected token at 1"

Comment: Can you echo the JSON object and then run it through jsonlint or something? Sounds like you maybe don't really have a JSON object or something else. If you are creating a JSON object and then doing `window.doSomething('` I think maybe the `'`' is the unexpected token?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Javascript Interface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) annotation which can be used to pass in / access the values from Java directly

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I might did not explained myself well. The JS gets the call from the native class (so I don't need the Javascript Interface). BUT, I pass a JSON string which does not being parse in the JS, and that's my problem...